# Why I am getting " parse error on input `<-' "?

Tags: haskell

Here is my code

```
lotto blacklista size board current = [black | blacklista<-action current , warunki blacklista,
                                                if end current
                                                   then if check board blacklista
                                                   then black <- blacklista
                                                          else False
                                                else black <- lotto blacklista size board (next current) ]
```

Can you tell me why I am getting parse error in this line?

```
then black <- blacklista
```

Comment: `black <- blacklista` is not an expression. The branches of an if-then-else must be expressions. I have no idea what you intended to do, so can't guess how to write it correctly.

Comment: Also, please include your code right here. Who knows if pastebin.com lives two years from now when someone comes across your question?

Comment: black is my list of results, I want to add an item to black when my iterator current is big enough (end current gives True) and expression check board blacklista gives me True. However I dont want to steb back if current isn't big enough(end current gives False), thats why I put here an if-then-else expression.

Comment: `blacklista <- action current` represents `blacklista` as drawn from the result of `action` applied to `current`; this doesn't make much sense if `blacklista` is already given as one of the parameters of `lotto`.

Comment: `blacklista` will be changing, at first it will be empty and after that it will be bigger and bigger. Maybe I can do `blacklista2 <- action current blacklista`and after that `black <- blacklista2`

Comment: Maybe I will ask another, similar question : `test :: Integer->[Integer]
test = [l| z <- [1..5] , if mod z 2 == 0 then l<-z else False ]` I want `l` to be list of even numbers, how can I do that?

Comment: @Pawel: `[z | z <- [1..5], mod z 2 == 0]` gives you the even numbers. No need for any `if` expressions, just put your condition directly in the list comprehension.

Comment: But Could you please use here `if` expression?

Comment: Yes you can use `if` but the result of that if expression should be bool and nothing else. So you can put any expression that result in a bool only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From whatever context you have provided, it seems you want something like this:

```
lotto blacklista size board current = let blist = action current warunki blacklista in
                                          [black | black <- if end current && check board blist then blist
                                                            else lotto blacklista size board (next current)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try Monad (new `do` block) after `then` and `else`.